# Access violation error with memcpy

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, windows-8.1, portable-executable

```
    unsigned char hexData[14] = {
    0x31, 0xC0, 0xBB, 0x42, 0x24, 0x80, 0x7C, 0x66,
    0xB8, 0x88, 0x13, 0x50, 0xFF, 0xD3
};

void dummy(){}

int main()
{
    void *code_ptr = &dummy;
    PDWORD OP;
    __asm
    {
        call code_ptr
        add code_ptr,10h
    }
    VirtualProtect(code_ptr, 14, PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, OP);
    memcpy(code_ptr, hexData, 14);
.
.
.
```

and in disassembly

```
_LoadLibraryA@4:
003C11E0  jmp         _LoadLibraryA@4 (03C1430h)  
dummy:
003C11E5  jmp         dummy (03C1A80h)  
_printf:
003C11EA  jmp         _printf (03C1436h)  
_VirtualProtect@16:
003C11EF  jmp         _VirtualProtect@16 (03C143Ch)  
003C11F4  int         3  
003C11F5  int         3  
003C11F6  int         3  
003C11F7  int         3
```

so it seems i can copy something 15 blocks after 003C11E5
but when i do that i get access Access violation error

I tried using VirtualAlloc like

```
void *code_ptr = &dummy;
code_ptr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 14, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy(code_ptr, hexData, 14);
__asm
{
    call code_ptr
}
```

and i got that error again

```
int (*func)();
func = (int (*)()) code;
(int)(*func)();
```

that not working either

my IDE is VS2013 and my OS is win8.1

I would appreciate any ideas

Comment: Conversion to poiner to void from the function type is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `OP` is an uninitialized pointer. You cannot pass that to `VirtualProtect`. Instead of

```
PDWORD OP;
```

you need:

```
DWORD OldProtect;
```

And then pass `&OldProtect` to `VirtualProtect`.

```
VirtualProtect(code_ptr, 14, PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, &OldProtect);
```

You existing code fails on the call to `VirtualProtect`. You don't check for errors and so continue regardless. Then the call to `memcpy` fails with a general protection fault, because the memory is read only.

Even if you fix your code, I doubt that it will work though. I see no reason for `dummy` to be 14 bytes long. You are relying on luck and wishful thinking. So you will probably overwrite the code that you are executing.

If you want 14 bytes of memory to write your code to, call `VirtualAlloc`. That way you can be certain of success.

As a piece of general advice, you will need to get into the habit of checking return values for errors. You call `VirtualProtect` and ignore the return value. How do you know that your call to `VirtualProtect` was successful?

Comment: it seem that i can pass uninitialized pointer to a function and there s no error on that
i said "I tried using VirtualAlloc like ....."

Comment: Well, since you did not check for errors, how can you possibly say that? Clue, stop ignoring the return value of `VirtualProtect`. Start by re-reading the documentation and concentrating on the return value.

Comment: Well, it's precisely as I say in the answer. You passed an uninitialized pointer look no further. There's always `GetLastError`.

Comment: GetLastError returns Invalid access to memory location

Comment: You passed an uninitialized variable. What else did you expect?

Comment: Thanks a lot it was all what you said